# mvn eclipse project generation missing one dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

using the below MVN pom file, I execute 'mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse'.  I get an Eclipse project that's configured with all the dependencies from my local repo in 'Libraries' - except Apache Mina.  Why is Mina missing from the Libraries, and how do I get it to be added along with the rest?  No errors are reported by mvn.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.blah.tab</groupId>
<artifactId>TAB</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TAB</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
        <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

additional info: 
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.6.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Did you run `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse you are using ? Are you using m2e or m2eclipse plugin ?

Comment: May be your local repo does not have Apache Mina !! .. Try connecting maven to use its remote repository.

Comment: Can you add version of maven and maven-eclipse-plugin you're using? It may be related to fact, that apache-mina's pom declare 'bundle' as packaging, not 'jar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the -X option to get more debug

Comment: turns out my <dependency> was missing the version info.